# how to update record using multidimensional array

Tags: arrays

I have this multidimensional array and i want to update record with these array  i want to update this record
what should i do :

```
array(
    [row_ids]=>array(
        [0]=>8
        [5]=>6
        [10]=>3
    )
    [category_name]=>array(
        [1]=>cate_19
        [6]=>cate_10
        [11]=>cate_3
    )
    [add_by]=>array(
        [2]=>1
        [7]=>1
        [12]=>1
    )
    [status]=>array(
        [4]=>active
        [9]=>active
        [14]=>active
    )

)



foreach(???? as ?? => ???){
update category_name='???', add_by='???', status='??' where row_id='??'
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some informations about what do you desire? Is it Javascript code?

Comment: this is php code and want to update record with four row